# How to handle multi-lines logs with spark streaming?

Tags: java, spark-streaming, rdd

I'm struggling to find a way to parse multi-lines logs using spark streaming. I created a parser that take an array of string as input parameter. When a multi-line stacktrace is found, it loops on each line until it reaches a 'normal' line before processing it.

The logs are injected via Flume on a kafka topic and received via KafkaUtils.createDirectStream.

When it comes to spark streaming, the stacktraces might be cut in the middle over 2 (or more) distributed RDDs. I'd be very lucky if it does not happen ...

My question is: what could I do to reconstruct the stacktraces that are cut before processing them?

Should I pre-process the RDDs and create new ones containing exactly what I'm waiting for?
Should I reconstruct the stacktraces via a global buffer?
Should I somehow play with the offsets? How exactly?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanx,

--mike